# Under what conditions on the matrices $A$ and $B$ does $AXA=B$ have infinitely many solutions $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The only things I can conclude are the dimensions of the matrices and the fact that $A$ is singular since otherwise only one solution would exist. I have no idea where to go next...

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148227/whats-the-solution-to-x-axa

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is invertible, then the only solution to $AXA = B$ is $X = A^{-1}BA^{-1}$.

If $A$ is not invertible, then we can apply the [vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operation on both sides to get $\text{vec}(B) = \text{vec}(AXA) = (A^T \otimes A)\text{vec}(X)$, where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Since $A$ is not invertible, $A^T \otimes A$ is also not invertible. So the system $(A^T \otimes A)\text{vec}(X) = \text{vec}(B)$ will either have no solutions or infinitely many solutions depending on $(A^T \otimes A)$ and $\text{vec}(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you can find one solution $X_0$, then any non-zero solution $Y$ to $AYA = 0$ will give you $A(X_0 + Y)A = B$. So really there is no condition on $B$ other than that there needs to exist at least one solution $X_0$ (and this is also a restriction on $A$). Then you want to know the conditions on $A$ that make $AXA = 0$ have infinitely many solutions, which is an easier problem to work with.

Comment: Thanks! Won't the first condition impose restrictions on A (in addition to B)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll modify the answer to reflect that point.

Comment: Singularity of A implies the existence of such a Y, given the row space of A contains a nonzero vector of it's null space, doesn't it?